# Replace char in column

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to delete the char `.` from a column in a table.

Column = n_license
table = fighters_fighter

Query I'm trying to use:

```
UPDATE `fighters_fighter` SET `n_license` = REPLACE (`n_license`,`.`,``);
```

Error:

> 1054 - Unknown column '.' in 'field list'

Which could be the problem?

Comment: Back-ticks are for column names, not for string literals. Try straight ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The char should be enclosed within `''` not the ``

```
UPDATE `fighters_fighter` 
SET `n_license` = REPLACE (`n_license`,'.','');
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrong quotes on the characters.

```
UPDATE fighters_fighter 
SET n_license = REPLACE (n_license,'.','');
```